# firing a CustomEvent in Polymer gives me "Exception: Class 'MyData' has no instance method '[]'"

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

```dart
class MyData {
  String name;
  String age;

  MyData(this.name, this.age);
}

... 
class AlertSimulatorElement extends PolymerElement {

void handleClick(e,d,t) {
   asyncFire('polymer-signal',detail: new MyData("Mike",99));

   // this works:
   //asyncFire('polymer-signal', detail: {'name': "foo", 'data': "Foo!"});
   }
}
```

asynFire gives me:

```dart
Exception: Class 'MyData' has no instance method '[]'.
NoSuchMethodError : method not found: '[]'
Receiver: Instance of 'MyData'
Arguments: ["name"]
```

I'm using Chromium Version 33.0.1750.48 (251129) and polymer 0.9.5

The Doc says I can use Object but this seems to be wrong? Any hints?
PolymerElement#fire: http://goo.gl/DYXMiZ
thx

Comment: What do you mean by Chromium. Did you actually mean Dartium or is this only in JavaScript?

Comment: I edited my answer. Please try if it works to fire the event this way. Maybe a bug in Polymer.

Answer (score 1):

Günter pointed my in the right direction - it is *a bug in polymer_signals.dart*

polymer_signals.dart (Line 49)

```dart
@initMethod
void registerListener() {
  // signal listener at document
  document.addEventListener('polymer-signal', (e) {
    _notify(e.detail['name'], e.detail['data']);
  });
}
```

As a workaround for now:

```dart
// (sender.dart)
asyncFire('polymer-signal',detail: { 'name' : "alertevent", 'data' : new MyData("Mike",47) });


// (receiver.html)
<polymer-element name="mm-alert-list" on-add-alert-event="{{handleAddAlert}}">
    ...
    <polymer-signals on-polymer-signal-alertevent="{{fooSignal}}"></polymer-signals>       
</polymer-element>

// (receiver.dart)
...
@CustomTag('mm-alert-list')
class AlertListElement extends PolymerElement {
...

fooSignal(final CustomEvent event, detail, sender){
    print('<br>[my-app] got a [' + detail.name + '] signal<br>');
}

...
}
```

});

[**Update**]
Filed a bug: https://github.com/ErikGrimes/polymer_elements/issues/143

Answer (score 0):

There was a limitation that only primitive types (String, int, double), List, Map or a List or a Map of on of them was allowed for event details. I thought this limitation was gone some months ago but maybe it came back.

**EDIT**

I just tried it without Polymer and it worked

```dart
var b = dom.querySelector('#button');
b.onClick.listen((e) {
  b.dispatchEvent(new dom.CustomEvent('polymer-signal',detail: new MyData("Mike","99")));
});
```

This should also work if you use `this` (your Polymer element) instead of `b`.

Comment: Thanks Günter, maybe it has something todo with the polymer-version or angular-version I'm using but I'm not able to upgrade my dependencies to the latest version. pup upgrade drives me crazy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982907/pub-upgrade-downgrades-my-main-packages