# pub upgrade downgrades my main-packages

Tags: dart, dart-pub

Here is my dependency-list:

```
dependencies:
  browser: any

  polymer: any
  polymer_elements: any

  angular: any

  lawndart: any
  validate: any
  http_utils: any
```

And here is what I get if I say "pub upgrade"

```
Resolving dependencies... (42.5s)
  analyzer 0.12.2 (4 newer versions available)
  angular 0.9.10
  args 0.9.0 (3 newer versions available)
  barback 0.11.1 (2 newer versions available)
  bignum 0.0.5
  browser 0.9.1 (3 newer versions available)
  cipher 0.6.0 (1 newer version available)
  code_transformers 0.0.1-dev.2 (4 newer versions available)
  collection 0.9.1
  crypto 0.9.0
  csslib 0.9.2
  custom_element 0.10.1
  di 0.0.34
  event_bus 0.2.3 (1 newer version available)
  fixnum 0.9.0
  html5lib 0.9.2 (1 newer version available)
  html_import 0.9.0
  http_utils 1.2.10
  intl 0.8.10+4 (9 newer versions available)
  json 0.10.0
  lawndart 0.6.5
  logging 0.9.1+1
  logging_handlers 0.8.0
  matcher 0.10.0
  meta 0.8.8
  mock 0.10.0+1
  mutation_observer 0.9.0
  observe 0.10.0-pre.0 (3 newer unstable versions available)
  path 1.1.0
  perf_api 0.0.8
  polymer 0.8.10+4 (15 newer versions available)
  polymer_elements 0.0.2 (16 newer versions available)
  polymer_expressions 0.9.1 (2 newer unstable versions available)
  route_hierarchical 0.4.17
  shadow_dom 0.9.2
  smoke 0.1.0-pre.2
  source_maps 0.9.0
  stack_trace 0.9.3+1
  template_binding 0.9.1 (2 newer unstable versions available)
  unittest 0.10.1+2
  unmodifiable_collection 0.9.2+1
  utf 0.9.0
  uuid 0.3.0
  validate 1.2.4
  yaml 0.9.0
```

**polymer** - 15 newer version!!!!

if I say "pub upgrade browser"

```
  analyzer 0.12.2 (4 newer versions available)
+ analyzer_experimental 0.8.6
< angular 0.0.7 (was 0.9.10) (15 newer versions available)
  args 0.9.0
  barback 0.11.1
  bignum 0.0.5
> browser 0.10.0+2 (was 0.9.1)
  cipher 0.6.0
  code_transformers 0.0.1-dev.2
  collection 0.9.1
  crypto 0.9.0
  csslib 0.9.2
  custom_element 0.10.1
  di 0.0.34
  event_bus 0.2.3
  fixnum 0.9.0
  html5lib 0.9.2
  html_import 0.9.0
  http_utils 1.2.10
  intl 0.8.10+4
+ js 0.2.2
  json 0.10.0
  lawndart 0.6.5
  logging 0.9.1+1
  logging_handlers 0.8.0
  matcher 0.10.0
  meta 0.8.8
  mock 0.10.0+1
  mutation_observer 0.9.0
  observe 0.10.0-pre.0
  path 1.1.0
  perf_api 0.0.8
  polymer 0.8.10+4
  polymer_elements 0.0.2
< polymer_expressions 0.8.10+4 (was 0.9.1) (2 newer versions available)
  route_hierarchical 0.4.17
  shadow_dom 0.9.2
  smoke 0.1.0-pre.2
  source_maps 0.9.0
  stack_trace 0.9.3+1
  template_binding 0.9.1
  unittest 0.10.1+2
  unmodifiable_collection 0.9.2+1
  utf 0.9.0
  uuid 0.3.0
  validate 1.2.4
  yaml 0.9.0
Changed 5 dependencies!
```

It downgrades angular!!!!!

**< angular 0.0.7 (was 0.9.10) (15 newer versions available)**

If I change my dependencies for browser:

```
dependencies:
  browser: ">=0.10.0+2 <0.11.0"
```

Results in:

```
> analyzer 0.13.5 (was 0.12.2)
  analyzer_experimental 0.8.6
  angular 0.0.7 (15 newer versions available)
> args 0.10.0+2 (was 0.9.0)
> barback 0.12.0 (was 0.11.1) (1 newer version available)
  bignum 0.0.5
  browser 0.10.0+2
  cipher 0.6.0 (1 newer version available)
> code_transformers 0.1.1+1 (was 0.0.1-dev.2)
  collection 0.9.1
  crypto 0.9.0
< di 0.0.24 (was 0.0.34) (10 newer versions available)
> event_bus 0.2.4 (was 0.2.3)
  fixnum 0.9.0
> html5lib 0.10.0 (was 0.9.2)
  http_utils 1.2.10
> intl 0.9.8 (was 0.8.10+4)
  js 0.2.2
  json 0.10.0
  lawndart 0.6.5
  logging 0.9.1+1
  logging_handlers 0.8.0
  matcher 0.10.0
  meta 0.8.8
  mock 0.10.0+1
> observe 0.10.0-pre.3 (was 0.10.0-pre.0)
  path 1.1.0
  perf_api 0.0.8
> polymer 0.10.0-pre.8 (was 0.8.10+4)
> polymer_elements 0.1.2+1 (was 0.0.2) (6 newer unstable versions available)
> polymer_expressions 0.10.0-pre.1 (was 0.8.10+4)
+ polymer_ui_elements 0.1.2 (6 newer unstable versions available)
  route_hierarchical 0.4.17
  smoke 0.1.0-pre.2
  source_maps 0.9.0
  stack_trace 0.9.3+1
> template_binding 0.10.0-pre.1 (was 0.9.1)
  unittest 0.10.1+2
  utf 0.9.0
  uuid 0.3.0
  validate 1.2.4
+ web_components 0.3.3
  yaml 0.9.0
```

I'm using Dart 1.3.0!!! so - this is the latest version for today.
I don't know what pub upgrade is doing here but it does not manage dependencies...

Any hints?

**[Update]**
As a workaround I change my dependencies to

```
dependencies:
  polymer_elements:
    git: https://github.com/ErikGrimes/polymer_elements

  polymer_ui_elements:
    git: https://github.com/ErikGrimes/polymer_ui_elements

  angular: any
  #  git: https://github.com/angular/angular.dart
  #    Incompatible version constraints on html5lib:
  #    - angular depends on version >=0.9.2 <0.10.0
  #    - polymer depends on version >=0.10.0 <0.11.0

  lawndart: any
  validate: any
  http_utils: any
```

Directly linking to GitHub solves almost everything.
Except Angular!!!!

```
Resolving dependencies... (50.0s)
< angular 0.0.7 (was 0.9.10) (15 newer versions available)
> barback 0.12.0 (was 0.11.1) (1 newer version available)
  cipher 0.6.0 (1 newer version available)
< di 0.0.24 (was 0.0.34) (10 newer versions available)
```

**Very frustrating**, it took me almost 3h to get the latest polymer version and angular is still 15 versions behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a discussion about a similar experience
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/angular-dart/0.0.7/angular-dart/PnvkUudHulg/ZtM3Y8xH_ugJ

I guess you should add version constraints on every dependency where weird (too old) versions are fetched until `pub upgrade` complaints that it is not able to resolve the dependencies.
This could help to find the culprit.

The `pub deps` command was added in Dart 1.4 to show which package dependes on which other packages.

Comment: Thx, yes - tried this already but gave up. I took another approach (see my updated question). It took me almost 3h to cheat "pub upgrade"...

Comment: So it seems (one of) the culprit(s) is polymer_elements. Sorry for that.There were a longer time where we didn't publish updates :( What if you add a version constraint on Angular?

Comment: Adding a version constraint to polymer_elements should have the same effect as the git dependency. As we published the recent updates as pre-release a very specific version constraint is needed to make `pub upgrade` fetch them: '>=0.2.0-pre.5'. Dependencies with a dash after the build number are not fetched without a constraint that enfores it.

Comment: If I use angular: "0.9.10" then I get Incompatible version constraints on analyzer:
- angular depends on version >=0.12.0 <0.13.0
- di depends on version >=0.10.0 <0.11.0

Comment: What you could still do is add a 
`dependency_overrides:
   analyzer: '>=0.12.0'`

Comment: Playing around with versionnumbers already drove my crazy this morning. :-) I filed an issue on GH/angular.dart for upgrading the  dependencies for html5lib. https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/883. This should solve my probs for today. Hope the Dart-Team will fix this problem asap...

Comment: I see. It is really hard to find such conflicts because `pub upgrade` doesn't provide enough information about conflicts yet.